# Integral $\int_{-1}^1\frac {1}{x^{2}}dx$ and its complex version

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I don't very understand about the difference of the following two integrals. As known, improper integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^2} dx = divergent
\end{equation}
is divergent due to the singularity at $x=0$. However, the integral ($\eta$ is a positively infinitesimal number and $C$ is a path on the complex plane from $-1$ to $1$)
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{(x+i\eta)^2} dx = \int_C \frac{1}{z^2} dz = -2
\end{equation}
result in a finite value.
(I understand the real axis version by, at $x=0$, the small imaginary part leads to a large negative contribution, which compensates the large positive contribution near $x=0$.)

My question is that is there any special technique that can be used to evaluate the integral of the form $\int_a^b \frac{1}{f(x+i\eta)} dx$? 
The residue theorem, from my understanding, can only be used to calculate the imaginary part of this kind of integral. However, how can I evaluate its real part? thanks in advance.

Comment: The function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$ is a meromorphic function with a double pole in $z=0$ with residue zero, hence $\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz $ for any contour $\gamma$ surrounding the origin is zero by the residue theorem.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \dfrac{1}{z^2} = \dfrac{d}{dz} \left(\frac{-1}{z}\right)$$
so for any path $C$ from $a$ to $b$ in the complex plane that avoids 
$0$, $$\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z^2} = -\frac{1}b + \frac1a$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, for the simple example of $1/z^2$, it is easy to calculate analytically. But what I want to ask is how to evaluate an integral like $Re [\int_a^b f(x+i\eta) dx] $ where $f(z)$ may have some poles on the real axis.

Comment: If you can find an antiderivative for $f$, analytic in a neighbourhood of the contour, the same principle applies.

Answer (score 0):

When the integrand has a primitive, the integral along any path just depends on the endpoints.  Thus the integral around a closed contour avoiding any singularities is zero.

$-1/z$ is a primitive for $1/z^2$.

Often by using a contour, you can calculate the integral along the real axis.  If you can show that the rest of the integral goes to zero, you can use Cauchy's integral formula or the residue theorem.